# Output for an RNN

Tags: neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm taking the Coursera course *Neural Networks for Machine Learning* hosted by Geoffrey Hinton from the University of Toronto and there is a quiz question in week 7 for which my answer differs from the right one.

The question goes like this:
[image]

One question is, how should I get a probability between 0 and 1 if the `Whh` weight is negative and the logistic `h` unit gives values between 0 and 1. Given the above, their linear combination will allways be negative.

A second question would be if we also have to use backpropagation in order to get the right answer?

The way I've started to tackle this question is the following:

```
h0 = 1/( 1 + exp(- (Whh * hbias + Wxh*x0)) )

h1 = 1/( 1 + exp(- (Whh * h0 + Wxh*x1)))

y1 = Why * h1
```

Which of my assumptions are incorrect?

Regards,
Cristian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this.**

```
h0 = sigmoid(x0*Wxh + hbias)
h1 = sigmoid(x1*Wxh + Whh*h0 + hbias)
y1 = h1*Why
```

Comment: hi, the answer will still be a negative number.

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: -0.3551 was correct when I submitted the answer last week. Weird.

Comment: Yes, You are right, I've miscalculated something. Second time I went trough the calculation it was right. Thanks!

Comment: But then the output can be negative? I don't know why I had the impresion that the output is a pobability.

Comment: y1 is just a output/prediction, it can be negative. If it was an activation, then you can say it can't be negative for a sigmoid function.