# How to build an RNN using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, recurrent-neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to Implement a Recurrent Neural Network using Numpy in python. I'm trying to implement a Many-to-One RNN, for a classification problem. I'm a little fuzzy on the psuedo code, especially on the BPTT concept. I'm comfortable with the forward pass ( not entirely sure if my implementation is correct ) but really confused with back ward pass, and I need some advice from experts in this field.

I did check out related posts : 
1) [Implementing RNN in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465813/implementing-rnn-with-numpy)

2) [Output for RNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044992/output-for-an-rnn)

3) [How can I build RNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987673/how-can-i-build-an-rnn-without-using-nn-rnn)

But I feel my issue is with understanding the psuedo code / concept first up, code in those posts is complete and have reached further stage than mine.

My Implementation is inspired from the tutorial:

[WildML RNN from scratch](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-2-implementing-a-language-model-rnn-with-python-numpy-and-theano/)

I did implement a Feed-Forward Neural Network following part of tutorial from the same author, but I'm really confused with this implementation of his. Andrew Ng's RNN video suggests 3 different weights ( Weights for activation, Input and Output layers ) but the above tutorial only has two sets of weights ( correct me if I'm wrong ).

The nomenclature in my code follows that of Andrew Ng's RNN pseudo code ...

I'm reshaping my input samples in to 3D ( batch_size, n_time steps, n_ dimensions ) ... Once , I reshape my samples I'm doing forward pass on each sample seperately ...

Here's my code:

```
def RNNCell(X, lr, y=None, n_timesteps=None, n_dimensions=None, return_sequence = None, bias = None):



'''Simple function to compute forward and bakward passes for a Many-to-One Recurrent  Neural Network Model.

This function Reshapes X,Y in to 3D array of shape (batch_size, n_timesteps, n_ dimensions) and then performs

recurrent operations on each sample of the data for n_timesteps'''

# If user has specified some target variable
if len(y) != 0:

    # No. of unique values in the target variables will be the dimesions for the output layer
    _,n_unique = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)

else:

    # If there's no target variable given, then dimensions of target variable by default is 2
    n_unique = 2


# Weights of Vectors to multiply with input samples
Wx = np.random.uniform(low = 0.0,

                       high = 0.3,

                      size = (n_dimensions, n_dimensions))

# Weights of  Vectors to multiply with resulting activations
Wy = np.random.uniform(low = 0.0,

                      high = 0.3,

                      size = (n_dimensions, n_timesteps))

# Weights of Vectors to multiple with activations of previous time steps
Wa = np.random.randn(n_dimensions, n_dimensions)


# List to hold activations of each time step
activations = {'a-0' : np.zeros(shape=(n_timesteps-1, n_dimensions),

                               dtype=float)}


# List to hold Yhat at each time step
Yhat = []

try:
    # Reshape X to align with the shape of RNN architecture
    X = np.reshape(X, newshape=(len(X), n_timesteps, n_dimensions))

except:

    return "Sorry can't reshape and array in to your shape"


def Forward_Prop(sample):

    # Outputs at the last time step
    Ot = 0

    # In each time step
    for time_step in range(n_timesteps+1):

        if time_step < n_timesteps:

            # activation G ( Wa.a<t> + X<t>.Wx )
            activations['a-' + str(time_step+1)] = ReLu( np.dot( activations['a-' + str(time_step)], Wa )   
                                            + np.dot(   sample[time_step, :].reshape(1, n_dimensions)    , Wx    ) )

        # IF it's the last time step then use softmax activation function
        elif time_step == n_timesteps:

            # Wy.a<t> and appending that to Yhat list
            Ot = softmax( np.dot( activations['a-' + str(time_step)], Wy ) ) 

    # Return output probabilities
    return Ot


def Backward_Prop(Yhat):

    # List to hold errors for the last layer
    error = []

    for ind in range(len(Yhat)):

        error.append(   y[ind] - Yhat[ind]  )

    error = np.array(error)

    # Calculating Delta for the output layer
    delta_out = error * lr 
    #* relu_derivative(activations['a-' + str(n_timesteps)])



    # Calculating gradient for the output layer
    grad_out = np.dot(delta_out.reshape(len(X), n_timesteps),
                      activations['a-' + str(n_timesteps)])


    # I'm basically stuck at this point

    # Adjusting weights for the output layer
    Wy = Wy - (lr * grad_out.reshape((n_dimesions, n_timesteps)))








for sample in X:

    Yhat.append( Forward_Prop(sample) )


Backward_Prop(Yhat)


return Yhat




  # DUMMY INPUT DATA
   X = np.random.random_integers(low=0, high = 5, size = (10, 10 ));

# DUMMY LABELS
y = np.array([[0],
             [1],
             [1],
             [1],
             [0],
             [0],
             [1],
             [1],
             [0],
             [1]])
```

I understand that my BPTT implementation is wrong, but I'm not thinking clearly and I need some experts' perspective on where exactly I'm missing the trick. I don't expect a detailed debugging of my code, I only require a high level overview of the pseudo code on back propagation ( assuming my forward prop is correct ). I think my fundamental problem can also be with the way I'm doing my forward pass on each sample individually.

I'm stuck on this problem since 3 days now, and it's really frustrating not being able to think clearly. I'd be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction and clear my confusion. Thank you for your time in advance !! I really appreciate it once again !